# Magento redirects to cart page when using Belvg Gift Extension

Tags: onepage-checkout

I have a magento website that is using Belvg Gifts extension but when the extension is active ite redirects to cart page when you are filling information on the onepage checkout step.

I check the errors using firebug console  I get the following

```
POST http://www.floridawinestore.com/checkout/onepage/saveMethod/ 403 (Session Expired)  prototype.js:1530
```

I conctacted the developer of the extension but said it works well but even when I install it using default Magento template it does not work. I have also tested with sevaral other templates but the same thing.

Here is the extension

```
http://www.floridawinestore.com/Belvg_Gifts-v.1.0.0.zip
```

If someone can help solve fix this extension I'll greatly appreciate

Thanks

Comment: after try to amend the code, is still not working tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, manage to make it work like this:
Go to 
`app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`

Somewhere around line 76 you will find: protected function `_expireAjax()`

Comment this lines:

```
$action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getCartWasUpdated(true)
&& !in_array($action, array('index', 'progress'))) {
$this->_ajaxRedirectResponse();
return true;
}
```

Hope this will help you,

Regards!

Comment: Recommending modification of a core Magento file is strongly in conflict with best practices.

Comment: I created custom OnepageController.php that extends this, then copied this function without the lines above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the solution was to check in

> System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart

and make sure that **After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart** is set to "**No**".

Apparently this redirects the user to the cart for some reason that I could not figure out.

My Network log in Chrome was saying that once the user tried to create an account the system was trying to save the address before the user wrote anything else and the redirect was triggered at JS level and not in PHP as @Raul suggested above.